# ‘In’ a meeting or ‘at’ a meeting? Which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know what preposition ‘meeting’ should take. Should I say I’m at a meeting or I’m in a meeting?

Comment: What meaning are you trying to convey?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct usage of ‘on’, ‘at’ and ‘in’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757/correct-usage-of-on-at-and-in) (and to pre-empt "In what way is this a duplicate?" I'll add that ['at the meeting or in the meeting?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484189/at-the-meeting-or-in-the-meeting/484221#484221) has already been closed as a duplicate of this. I might disagree.)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the difference lies in actively and passively participating.

*In a meeting* means you are actively participating in the meeting.

> "I'm busy right now. I'm in a meeting."

*At a meeting* means you are present at a meeting but not necessarily participating.

> "When you are at a meeting you have to talk quietly when taking a phone call."